# Why call interface properties statically and pass as parameters

Tags: php, oop

I recently came across some PHP where there were constants defined in an interface which were then called statically and passed to a method in the object implementing that interface.

What purpose would this serve? I guess the values that would be passed into that method will then be updated / changed in one place but there's no way of enforcing that with type hinting on that methods parameters so any thing could be passed in?

Example:

```
interface test_inter {
  const foo = "bar"
}

class test_obj implements test_inter {
  public function test_func( string $test_param ) {
  }
}

$obj = new test_obj();
$obj->test_func(test_inter::foo);
```

Possibly some syntax errors there as I've just typed it as a demo, my question is more about the why something like this would be implemented (or even should?) rather than any small errors in the above example.

Comment: any answer would pretty much be a matter of opinion, which is not typically `on topic` for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to define values/constants that each implementation will share and use, e.g.:

```
interface HttpRequest {
    const GET  = 1;
    const POST = 2;
    ...

    public function makeRequest($type);
}

...

$req = new RequestImpl();
$req->makeRequest(HttpRequest::POST);
```